# Why is my IOException not printing correct stacktrace in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, exception

I'm in JUnit, testing to see if file mocking works right. Something is going wrong and an exception is being thrown, yet it gives the reason as my "fail" call.

```
@Test
public void readFile() {
  RegistryTask task = new RegistryTask(false, null);
  try {
    FileSystem fs = Jimfs.newFileSystem(Configuration.unix());
    Path foo = fs.getPath("/foo");
    Files.createDirectory(foo);
    String text = "hello world!";

    Path hello = foo.resolve("hello.txt"); // /foo/hello.txt
    Files.write(hello, ImmutableList.of(text), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Path filepath = Paths.get("/foo/hello.txt");
    byte[] readBytes = Files.readAllBytes(filepath); // line 65
    // String readString = new String(readBytes);

    // assertEquals(text, readString);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    String err = e.getStackTrace().toString();
    fail("IOException:\n" + err); // line 71
  }
}
```

I uncommented line-by-line to see which line causes the failure. I want to debug with a real message but the output from my fail is this:

```
readFile(RegistryTaskTest)  Time elapsed: 0.132 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: IOException:
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@363ee3a2
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at RegistryTaskTest.readFile(RegistryTaskTest.java:71)
```

How is it printing out the string related to calling fail, vs the IOException? I would expect to see *something* related to line 65.

**Comments below explain why this was a duplicate.**

Comment: Because `catch (IOException e)` means you handled it!

Comment: Why bother catching it at all? Just add `throws IOException` to the signature of `readFile()`, and let JUnit handle printing the exception. Your custom message adds no value over what is done by default.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Not sure how this is duplicate because I am actually printing a string just fine. Also, I'm not calling a `readFile` method of my own right now. I was just verifying some vsf stuff before actually calling my class' methods. If I don't do a catch, I get a compilation error for not catching.

@SiKing: I caught it, but I would think the trace is from `e`, so it would give the details.

Comment: I edited my question as to why this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @DaveStein "I am actually getting a string printed fine" well, you're printing *a* string, for sure. But what you're actually printing is the result of printing a `StackTraceElement[]`; and since arrays don't override `toString()`, all you're getting is the class name and hash code, just the same as if you print `new int[0].toString()`. So, if you want a string related to the `IOException`, check the duplicate.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah. The way you explained it there makes sense to me. I have virtually no Java experience so I need things spelled out sometimes.